# Dictionary disappearing

Tags: python

I'm trying to assign scores to a list of words (e.g. amazed = 7, awesome = 10), however, it seems that my dictionary completely resets every time after I call the function. What can I do to make sure my dictionary remains constant so that I can use it to assign a score to the next list within the list? Here is my code:

```
data = open("keywords.txt","r")

def main():
    list = [["haha", "amazed", "amazing"], ["great", "wow", "awesome"]]
    print(keyword_check(list[0]))
    print(keyword_check(list[1]))

def keyword_check(list):

    keywords = []
    words = []
    numbers = []
    score_list = []
    total_score = 0
    dictionary = {}

    for i in data.readlines():
        list_split = i.split(",")
        list_stripped = [x.strip() for x in list_split]#for entries in i]
        keywords.append(list_stripped)

    file_length = len(keywords)

    for i in range(file_length):
        word = keywords[i][0]
        number = keywords[i][1]
        words.append(word)
        numbers.append(number)

    for i in range(file_length):
        dictionary[words[i]] = numbers[i]

    for i in list:
        if i in dictionary:
            score = dictionary[i]
            score_list.append(score)

    for i in score_list:
        total_score += int(i)

    return(dictionary, score_list, total_score)

main()


data.close()
```

Comment: Also, using names like `list` for variables overrides builtin python names and is bad practice and will lead to hard to find bugs.

Comment: I'll definitely change it. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You explicitly reset your dict in `keyword_check`, so of course it can't work as intended. One way around this is to define your dict in `main` and pass it as argument to the other function:

```
def main():
    list = [["haha", "amazed", "amazing"], ["great", "wow", "awesome"]]
    dictionary = {}
    print(keyword_check(list[0], dictionary))
    print(keyword_check(list[1], dictionary))

def keyword_check(list, dictionary):

    keywords = []
    words = []
    numbers = []
    score_list = []
    total_score = 0
    # dictionary = {} remove that line

    ...
```

Comment: I know it's copied from his question, but using a name like `list` for a list should be changed.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still a beginner with python, so I'm not quite sure what you mean when you say to "pass it as argument to the other function". After defining my dict in main and removing the dictionary = {} from my "keyword_check" function, my function won't work now as my dictionary is not defined for the rest of the function to process.

edit: nvm, I'm an idiot, i know what you mean now lol. Thanks!